# RxJava: concatMap() with zip() gets stuck

Tags: kotlin, rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I have a dummy network data source:

```
    fun networkDataSource(): Single<List<Int>> {
        return Single.just((0 until 100).toList())
                .delay(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
```

Here is an endless observable. It's main use is that it's calculation should be 'protected', so that **it calculates it's single value only once**. *(Here the value is the 1.)*

```
    val endless = Observable
            .just(1)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            // Counts as heavy operation, do not calculate this here once again
            .doOnNext { println("=> E: Calculated once") }
            .cache()
            //.doOnNext { println("=> E: From cache") }
            .repeat()
```

The main stream just simply emits values:

```
    val mainStream = Observable.range(0, 6)
            .doOnNext { println("=> M: Main stream $it") }
```

The task:

Zip the 3 observables together, and optimize the network usage, so that it will not be called more than necessary. (Once the number of data - integers in this case - is met.

Approach:

```
    mainStream
            .concatMap {index ->
                Observables.zip(
                        Observable.just(index),
                        endless,
                        networkDataSource()
                                .toObservable()
                                .doOnNext { println("#> N: Network data fetch $index") }
                )
            }
            .doOnNext { println("=> After concatmap: ${it.first}") }
            .take(4)
            .doOnNext { println("=> After take: ${it.first}") }
            .subscribe(
                    { println("=> Last onnext") },
                    { it.printStackTrace() },
                    { synchronized(check) { check.notifyAll() } }
            )
```

Finishing the locked thread - only needed for testing:

```
synchronized(check) {
    check.wait()
}
println("Ending")
```

Here is the output:

```
=> M: Main stream 0
=> M: Main stream 1
=> M: Main stream 2
=> M: Main stream 3
=> M: Main stream 4
=> M: Main stream 5
#> N: Network data fetch 0
=> E: Calculated once
=> After concatmap: 0
=> After take: 0
=> Last onnext
#> N: Network data fetch 1
=> After concatmap: 1
=> After take: 1
=> Last onnext
```

This the output and it is stuck after the second take. (Doesn't proceed in a minute). My question is, why does that happen?

As a sidenote, if I uncomment the line from the `endless` observable:

```
.doOnNext { println("=> E: From cache") }
```

It is going to flood the console with that line. Why is `endless` called so many times instead for each iteration?

`flatMap()` is not a solution here, because it does not take `take(4)` into account and proceeds to finish all network calls.

So how could I make `concatMap()` work?

(I also added *RxJS* tag because this is a reactive problem and absolutely not about Kotlin. JS solutions are also welcome, if those functions exist in the RxJava library.)

Edit.:

I looked into the code and the 2 outputs are probably because of the `prefetch` parameter:

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final <R> Observable<R> concatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends ObservableSource<? extends R>> mapper) {
    return concatMap(mapper, 2);
}
```

But I still don't understand how it works. I've only read that `concatMap()` is `flatmap()`, but it waits for the results of each.

Comment: The whole setup will likely run on the same thread after the first item and the `repeat` in `endless` will never give up the thread, preventing any other operator from progressing.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you, you are right, but I wouldn't have thought about that. Added `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` after `repeat()` in the `endless` observable and it completes now. Though it emits way too many after the `repeat()` and `throttleFirst` would be too much of a hack to add in the end.

--- Could you please explain or give a link what the rx-way would be to solve my problem? This one I am currently doing looks hacky and far from professional, would not want to keep it in an android app.--- 

--- Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It makes no sense to me to repeat that cache because you'll only ever use one and only item of it.

Comment: @akarnokd Wow, thanks, didn't realize it would work without the `repeat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

The whole setup will likely run on the same thread after the first item and the `repeat` in `endless` will never give up the thread, preventing any other operator from progressing. It makes no sense to me to repeat that `cache` because you'll only ever use one and only item of it.